# Don't stop the Chronometer when the app is switch off (onStop)

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to keep a chronometer running while the app is completely switched off. the chronometer doesn't stop while the app is in the background which is good but it stops if the app is shut down.

Comment: When does the chronometer need to be running? If it only needs to run when the device is turned on, a service is your best bet. However if you want accurate time change when the device is fully powered off, you should just save the time when the app is shut down and recalculate on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have little knowledge of Android development, an application that is shut down has no way of tracking time. To get around this you must simply save the date and time when the app shuts down and recalculate when it turns back on. If you fear the user will change the local time, you can use a web api such as http://timezonedb.com/api to get the current time regardless of user changes. This does however require the user to have an internet connection.

Comment: Java, like nearly every language, has simple built-in methods for reading the system clock. No Internet connection is necessary.

Comment: @chrylis, if you read the whole post you will see that the internet connection is only needed if you are worried the user will change their system clock.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when something needs to be done offline, it is done in a `service`.

[image]
(www.slideshare.net)

Assuming you don't know what a service is, from the docs:

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding
>    declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services
>   can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

So basically, its just something that runs in the background, including when the screen is off. You may face a problem that your service gets killed by the system, as the android docs specify:

> Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may
>   be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this
>   happens, the system will later try to restart the service. An
>   important consequence of this is that if you implement
>   onStartCommand() to schedule work to be done asynchronously or in
>   another thread, then you may want to use START_FLAG_REDELIVERY to have
>   the system re-deliver an Intent for you so that it does not get lost
>   if your service is killed while processing it.

In this case, you will need to add certain code to keep the service in the **foreground** and make sure that it doesn't get killed:

```
startForeground();//keeps service from getting destroyed.
```

The only problem that this could provide is a constant notification for the time that the service is alive.

You may also use `startSticky()`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
       // stopped, so return sticky.
       return START_STICKY;
}
```

If you are done:

```
stopSelf();
```

to stop the service, or:

```
Context.stopService();
```

This notification is not much of a problem though, because the screen is most likely off while the service is running. You can also customize your notification, and it is better for the user to know what is going on in the background.

### **To check if screen is off:**

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
```

If you need any more help, feel free to ask.

~Ruchir